# Proper way to construct strongly typed enum from integer

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Given that `static_cast<MyEnum>(userInt)` might lead to Undefined Behaviour if `userInt` is not mapped, what's the proper way to construct a strongly typed enum from an integer inputted by the user?

Also, I'd like to set it to a default value if the inputted value is not mapped in the enum.

One solution is:

```
switch (userInt)
{
    case 1:
        selEnum = myEnum1;
        break;
    case 2:
        selEnum = myEnum2;
        break;
    default:
        selEnum = myEnum2;
        error = true;
        break;
}
```

But I don't like that I have to remember to update it if I changed the enum values.

Comment: Why do you think that's UB?

Comment: The value is only unspecified if the input is outside the range of the underlying type of the enum, so you can verify that easily. Or do you mean you want to restrict the input to the values for which you have enumerators defined?

Comment: Exactly that @Praetorian. I want to detect that the value is not defined and set it to the default value instead.

Comment: Edited to explicitly name the context in which it will be UB

Comment: " I'd like to set it to a default value if the inputted value is not mapped in the enum." - failing silently like that is always a mistake.

Comment: In my code I report success/failure, this is an example. But edited to your satisfaction.

Comment: You can achieve your goal (before C++20 reflection) only with help of preprocessor - like boost.preprocessor. You can define list of enum values using BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM and in similar way a function that validates the real vlaues

Comment: "I don't like that I have to remember to update it if I changed the enum values". True, but there's a compiler warning for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily test whether the integer is inside the range of the underlying type, then use a `switch` on the enum values:

```
MyEnum convert_from_untrusted_int(int userInt)
{
    using limits = std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type_t<MyEnum>>>;

    auto const defaultValue = myEnum2;

    if (userInt < limits.min() || userInt > limits.max())
        return defaultValue;

    auto const e = MyEnum(userInt);
    switch (e) {
      case myEnum1:
      case myEnum2:  // compiler will warn if we miss one
        return e;
    }
    // we only get here if no case matched
    return defaultValue;
}
```

This does depend on you using sufficient compiler warnings that missing enumerators will be picked up in the `switch`, of course.